# Can I create deep jquery.ui.widget options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it good/bad practice to use deep nested options when creation a jquery.ui.widget

Something like the below? If a user wanted to say after initialization change the option for `height` in `outContainer` css, would they have to replace the entire `css` object within options?

```
options: {
    views: null,
    transitionTypes: {
        showView: { transition:slide, mode:show},
        hideView: { transition:slide, mode:hide}
    },
    css: {
        outContainer: {
            height: '0',
            display: 'none'
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/joeflateau/tryTT/

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather have a good sectioned options-object than a large list.
Beware of setting good default values though, so you don't have to pass a large object to the plugin on init...

As for the manipulating object afterwards:
I'd let the dev manipulate a set of "public" properties and then do a "redraw" of the plugin (not a total new object, but merely a soft re-init).

```
object.css.outContainer.height = "100";
object.redraw();
```

Comment: That's a good idea actually but is there any reason why you should NOT  bypass the options infrastructure provided by jquery.ui.widget?

Comment: I looked into the widget factory, as I haven't worked with it a lot..
and you can work with the _refresh to update the properties in an elegant way. Joe Flateau made a nice example of it with the _create method. I suggest you implement the _refresh method aswell, so can alter an object dynamically AND have the widget sort it out immediately. My solution is more for a custom plugin than the widget factory.

Comment: Appearently the Widget has some $.extend(true, obja, objb) like functionality and Joe's fiddle proves this.